# can change color when OnScrollListener() be implemented in change colors

Tags: android, colors, background, screen

Am working on a basic flashlight app and would like for the colors of the screen to change as i scroll thru the screen. I have been looking for some examples on how to do this but have had no luck. was hoping someone could point me in the right direction. So far i know i have to use `OnScrollListener()`
Thank you

Comment: How would you like the colors' to change? Do you mean a gradient? Random color? Are we going from one color to another? Black to white? Red to green? What are we trying to do man?!

Comment: if possible i would like to use colorsafe for android screen like the color spectrum from red to blue, also thank you for anwsering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was taken from [MindTheRobot](http://mindtherobot.com/blog/272/android-custom-ui-making-a-vintage-thermometer/)

```
Paint paint = new Paint();
int color = 0x00000000;
float position = getRelativeTemperaturePosition();
if (position < 0) {
    color |= (int) ((0xf0) * -position); // blue
} else {
    color |= ((int) ((0xf0) * position)) << 16; // red          
}
//Log.d(TAG, "*** " + Integer.toHexString(color));
LightingColorFilter logoFilter = new LightingColorFilter(0xff338822, color);
paint.setColorFilter(logoFilter);
```

Comment: for somereason the getRelativeTemperaturePosition() gives me an error, do you know what could be?

Comment: Sorry, I copied the code over from MindTheRobot. That method refer sthe the current linear value of your "graph". Essentially, it's the value between red and blue that you want. This value would be based on your scroll percent.